# why the ls -R (recursing down) doesn't work with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, ls

In my case, the directory tree is following

```
[peter@CentOS6 a]$ tree  
.  
├── 2.txt  
└── b  
    └── 1.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

why the following two command does only get 2.txt?

```
[peter@CentOS6 a]$ ls -R *.txt
2.txt
[peter@CentOS6 a]$ ls -R | grep *.txt
2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear if you are asking "why" meaning "explain the output" or "how should it be done". Steephen has already answered the latter, this is an answer to the former.

The reason for that is called "shell expansion". When you type *.txt in the command line, the program doesn't get it as a parameter, but rather the shell expands it and then passes the results.

*.txt expands to be "all files in the current directory with arbitrarily many symbols in the beginning, ending with '.txt' and not starting with '.'".

This means that when you type "`ls -R *.txt`" the command that actually executes is "`ls -R 2.txt`"; and when you do "`ls -R | grep *.txt`" it actually executes "`ls -R | grep 2.txt`".

This is the exact reason why Steephen has put quotation marks around the wildcard in the answer provided. It is necessary to stop this expansion. In fact you could also do so with single quotes or by placing a slash before any special character. Thus any of the following will work:

```
find . -name "*.txt"
```

or

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

or

```
find . -name \*.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for clear directions. I readly confused about "shell expansion" and "regex".

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, your shell is expanding `*.txt` into `2.txt` before the argument hits the command. So, you are in effect running

```
ls -R 2.txt
ls -R | grep 2.txt
```

You can't tell `ls` to look for a file pattern - that's what `find` is for. In the second case, you should quote your expression and use a proper regex:

```
ls -R | grep '\.txt'
```

Comment: that's it, so OP is doing parameter expension instead of a regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use find as follows to list all matching files in current and sub directories

```
find . -name "*.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The other problem that nobody has mentioned yet is that, beyond the fact that the shell intercepts the `*` before `grep` sees it, the shell treats `*` differently from `grep`.

The shell uses file globbing, and `*` means "any number of characters".

`grep` uses regular expressions, and `*` means "any number of the preceding item".

What you need to do is

```
ls -R | grep .\*\\.txt
```

which will

- escape the `*` so your shell does not intercept it
- properly format the regular expression the way `grep` expects
- properly escape the `.` in `.txt` to ensure that you have file extensions